# Range to IMG is empty when sent

Tags: excel, vba, image, email, outlook

I use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48897439/14866652 to a range as an image into an Outlook email.

I don't want the screen to display so I changed the `.Display` to `.Send`. The mail is sent empty:

```vb
Public Sub enviarmail()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim Email As Object
    Dim Sht As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    
    Set Sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Cierre de ventas")
    Set rng = Sht.Range("B23:N35")
    rng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
    
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Email = olApp.CreateItem(0)
    Set wdDoc = Email.GetInspector.WordEditor
    
    With Email
        .BodyFormat = 2
        .To = Range("D13").value
        .CC = Range("D14").value
        .Subject = Range("D15").value
           
        wdDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdChartPicture
        wdDoc.Range.InsertAfter vbLf & vbLf & "Firmado: " & Range("K13").value
 
        With wdDoc
            .InlineShapes(1).Height = 260
        End With
  
        .Send
            
    End With
    
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    
    Set Email = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
   
End Sub
```

Update: after several tests, [@urdearboy's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65397038/4539709) Potential Workaround #2 works, no need to use a buffer too, I've tried before without the buffer and I did not got it to work.

Using `.Display` and `.Send` at the same time works.

Comment: So this works when you change the action to `.Display` without making any other changes?

Comment: Exactly, it works flawlessly with .Display , if i set .Send it sends email empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Potential Workaround #1

I've ran into a similar issue that **only** occurs when adding objects to body outside of text or a direct file upload. The only way I have been able to solve is to add a time buffer between the file being added and the email being sent.

I know the answer here is not satisfying, but worth a try:

```
Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#
.Send
```

Here is the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59866738/email-macro-pauses-every-40-50-emails) I posted with issue. I bountied this and still got no solution so settled with the time delay eventually

---

### Potential Workaround #2

You can also try to first display and then send email. Same as above, this seems like a workaround to the actual problem but may be worth a try. If you are just sending one email then this could be a acceptable route to go. If many, then it may slow down the process and become less ideal.

```
With Email

    'Email Attributes
    .Display
    .Send

End With
```

Comment: Thank you @urdearboy, I havent think of that, sadly, I get same output, an empty email.

Comment: I've placed it in several and different spots, tried with +3 seconds and sadly same issue. I've tried also in a different PC but it remains the same.

Thank you for your persistence.

Comment: Wonder if you can display email and then send it. Still feels like a workaround to the actual problem but curious if that works

Comment: you got it right!!

I've previously  tried .display and .send with no results but, adding a buffer and using them both together did work!

So, the solution is :  
Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#
.Display
.Send

Thank you one more time

Comment: lol surprised to hear both are needed to get this to work. Still curious to know if there is a way to directly address the issue rather using workarounds that I shared. I would not be offended if you didn't accept my solution to see if anyone comes in with a better solution